# Abstract POV over affine varieties

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $k=\bar k $ be a field. An affine variety can be viewed as $\operatorname {MaxSpec }A$, that is a space with the Zariski topology, for a finitely generated $k$-algebra $A$. The morphisms of
affine varieties $\operatorname {MaxSpec }A'\to \operatorname {MaxSpec }A$, with $A'$ another finitely generated $k$-algebra, are those continuous maps induced via contraction by the homomorphisms $A\to A'$. Observe that if $h\in A$, and $I\subseteq A$ is an ideal, the homomorphisms $A\to A_h$ and $A\to A/I$ induce the inclusion (homeomorphism onto the image) in $\operatorname {MaxSpec }A$ of, respectively, a distinguished open set and a closed set, that are affine varieties as well.

In order to build  the structure of ringed space on $X:=\operatorname {MaxSpec }A$, use that an $f\in A$ induces a map $\hat  f:X\to k$, defined on $\mathfrak m\in X$ as the image of $f$ in the quotient $A'/\mathfrak m=k$. The regular maps on an open set $U\subseteq X$ now are those maps $U\to   k$ such that, for some cover of $U$ made by the disjoint open sets $X_{h_1},\dots, X_{h_n}\subseteq U$, with $h_1,\dots,h_n\in A$, the map  $X_{h_i}\hookrightarrow U\to k$ coincides with $\hat g$ for some $g\in A_{h_i}$, for all $i$. Observe that the $k$-algebra of the regular maps on an entire affine variety, say $\operatorname {MaxSpec }B$, is just the (finitely generated) $k$-algebra $B$.

If, as above, $\hat f :X\to k$ is a regular map and $\varphi^*:X':=\operatorname {MaxSpec }A'\to X$ is the morphism induced by $\varphi:A\to A'$, the pullback respect to $\varphi^*$ sends $\hat f$ to $\widehat{\varphi(f)}$, so it is a homomorphism (namely $\varphi$). Moreover if $s:U\to k$ is a regular map on the open set $U=X_{h_1}\cup\dots\cup X_{h_n}$, the pullback of $s$ can be obtained gluing the pullbacks, of the restrictions of $s$ to the various $X_{h_i}$, via the  morphisms $\varphi{^*}^{-1}(X_{h_i})=X'_{\varphi(h_i)}\to X_{h_i}$, induced  by $A_{h_i}\to A'_{\varphi(h_i)}$.

So far it has been showed that from $A\to  A'$ one recovers via  contraction a continuous map $X'\to X$, such that the pullbacks preserve the regularity of maps and are homomorphisms. Plus for a continuous  map  $X'\to  X$ having these properties, the pullback on the entire $X$ is a homomorphism $A'\to A$. It  has already been said that starting with $A\to A'$, the induced $X'\to X$ leads again to the initial homomorphism. Conversely, if the homomorphism $\alpha^*:A\to  A'$  is obtained by a map $\alpha:X'\to X$ with the mentioned properties, then $\alpha^*$ induces $\alpha$ via contraction: in fact, if $x_1,\dots,x_m\in A$ are a set of generators, for any $\mathfrak n\in X'$, the point $\alpha (\mathfrak n)\in X$ satisfies $\hat x_j(\alpha(\mathfrak n))=\widehat{\alpha^* (x_j)}(\mathfrak n)$ for all $j$; equivalently, $\alpha(\mathfrak n)/(x_j)=\alpha^*(x_j)/\mathfrak n$, so that $\alpha(\mathfrak n)$ is the contraction of $\mathfrak n$ via $\alpha^*$.

My doubt is  the following. For a  prevariety $Y$, we consider a continuous map  $Y\to X$, where $X$ is the same affine variety as  before, such that the pullbacks on the open sets of $X$ preserve the regularity and are $k$-algebras  homomorphisms; so such  a map comes with a homomorhism of $k$-algebras $A\to  R:=\mathcal O_Y(Y)$. Conversely a homomorphism $A\to  R$ induces a map $Y\to X$, since knowing the pullbacks of $\hat x_1,\dots,\hat x_m$ to $Y$ allows to determine uniquely a point in $Y$ from every point of $X$. Starting from a morphism $Y\to  X$ and making the cycle, we find the  initial  morphism; hence the (set-theoretic) map  from morphisms $Y\to X$ in the homomorphisms $A\to  R$ is still injective. I read  that it isn't  surjective though,  so  I'd  expect that the map $\phi^*:Y\to X$ induced by a homomorphism $\phi:A\to R$ is not a morphism in general. However,  intuitively, if we view $\phi$ as a map into $k^m$, it is obtained as $(r_1,\dots,r_m)$  for  $r_1,\dots,r_m\in R$.  It seems strange to  me  that a map defined in this way from regular  maps is  not necessarily  a  morphism; could  you  make an example of this situation? Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you think this? By [01I1](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01I1) if $X$ is a LRS and $Y$ an affine scheme there is a bijection between $Hom_{LRS}(X,Y)$ and $Hom_{Ring}(\mathcal{O}_{Y}(Y),\mathcal{O}_X(X))$ by sending each map to the pullback on global sections.

Comment: From the answer to this other question I just thought that when $X$ is a prevariety and $Y$ an affine variety, the map $Mor (X,Y)\to Mor (\mathcal O_Y(Y),\mathcal O_X(X))$ is only injective

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4400767/morphisms-of-prevarieties

Comment: Yeah, that's not quite right. Perhaps you should inform the person who wrote that answer about the issue. I'm sure they'd appreciate the knowledge.